# Anti-corruption layer with passing down attribute directives from an angular element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I've had to switch the selectbox library and I have reason to think I'll have to again in the future. The standard way to handle this sort of thing is an anti-corruption layer by creating your own wrapper so that you have a single point that you can modify to get the new functionality.

I can't quite figure out how to do that with angular however, since attribute directives placed on my directive would have to be passed through to the directive it is wrapping.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
<my-selectbox ng-model="foo" ng-required ng-class="{foo: bar}">
</my-selectbox>
```

and have that create something like

```
<my-selectbox>
    <select ng-model="foo" ng-required ng-class="{foo: bar}">
        ....
    </select>
</my-selectbox>
```

for the sake of simplicity, I'm not worried about transclusion or the options for the select for now, I just want to know how to bind the attribute directives to the wrapped directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `replace` is deprecated I would suggest you don't use `ng-` attributes, especially `ng-class` and rather use your own attribute prefixes.

Here's a theoretical approach that parses any attributes to `template` function of directive. The attribute parser replaces `my` prefix with `ng` prefix

```
app.directive('mySelectbox', function() {

  function parseAttributes(att) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < att.length; i++) {
      var name = att[i].nodeName.replace('my', 'ng');
      res.push(name + '="' + att[i].nodeValue + '"');
    }
    return res.join(' ');
  }

  return {
    template: function(el, attrs) {
      return '<select '+parseAttributes(el[0].attributes) +'></select>';          
    }
  }

});
```

HTML

```
<my-selectbox 
      my-model="active" 
      my-required 
      my-class="{foo: bar}" 
      my-options="item for item in items"></my-selectbox>
```

Produces

```
<select ng-model="active" 
        ng-required="" 
        ng-class="{foo: bar}" 
        ng-options="item for item in items" ></select>
```

The attributes left on element won't get manipulated by any core directives since they aren't `ng-` based.

This could also be done using `$compile` and `replaceWith()` or using `require:'^ngModel` but since I've never written an attribute parser I wanted to try doing it in template function since the overall template is not complex

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6eKmkzS7QKfOKRdmkjqq?p=preview)**</kbd>